# How to transform asset browser assets that are linked

Tags: asset-browser, asset, library-overrides

I'm relatively new to the use of the asset browser and library overrides.  I'm trying to set up a scene that uses linked assets; I have all the assets in another Blender file, and I have the asset browser all set up.  I want the assets to be linked (rather than appended) when I drag-and-drop them from the browser into the scene, so that any updates that have to be made to the original model will automatically be reflected in the scene.  However, when I have it set to "linked", I can't modify the transforms.  I figure it has to do with library overrides, but I'm struggling to find anything online that makes sense.

Can someone explain how (if it's possible) to edit the transforms for linked assets from the asset browser?  (Preferably I would rather not have to manually add a library override to the asset every time I drag-and-drop it into the scene; I get the impression this might have to do with adding the override to a collection that the assets are automatically placed in, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: perhaps check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250467/111042)

Comment: AFAIK linking from the asset browser and linking with File > Link doesn't change the behaviour of the linked object, so your question can be broadened to any linked object fwiw